# Doubling quotes in a string

Tags: sql, delphi, insert, double, quotes

I'm doing a sql query (insert) with Ado in Delphi. Some of my inserts have values with quotes ' . So in order to insert them with quotes you need to double them. So i made a function:

My logic here is to use a while loop cause i will modify the length of my word checked so i have control over the increment variable and i can increment properly to not get a endless loop. So i'm checking each character of the string and if it's a quote i add another one to it.

Here the code i use:

```
    //Search if there are ', if yes we need escape them
    if Pos('''', aSourceData[i,j]) <> 0 then
      begin
        long := 0;
        While long < Length(aSourceData[i,j]) do
          begin
            if aSourceData[i,j][long] = '''' then
              begin
                //here we found a ' copy string to it and double '
                aSourceData[i,j] := Copy(aSourceData[i,j], 0, long) + ''''
                                   + Copy(aSourceData[i,j], long+1, Length(aSourceData[i,j]));
                //we modified the string so the length of the word changed
                //make sure to increment correctly or it's a endless loop
                long := long +2;

              end;
            //Increment
            long := long +1 ;
            //if we don't check if the last character isn't a '
            //the loop will end before checking it and cause errors in sql string
            if (long = Length(aSourceData[i,j])) AND (aSourceData[i,j][long] = '''') then
              begin
                //double the ' if found at the last position
                aSourceData[i,j] := aSourceData[i,j] + '''';
                break;
              end;
          end;
      end;
```

This things works in most cases. But sometimes with the exact same word my function adds too many quotes example usually it does:

```
I''m
```

So when  insert `I''m` with an sql statement it will obviously work. But sometimes, this code bugs idk why and it inserts:

```
I'''''''''''''m
```

(Number of quotes ares random here). And idk why, it does end up quiting adding quotes but idk why sometimes it works great and sometimes it bugs and adds way too many quotes.

The thing is that in most cases it will double the quotes correctly. But sometimes idk why it goes crazy and adds too much quotes.

I'm searchin for doubling quotes cause in SQL you have to double them to escape them and be able to insert it properly in your table like:

```
Insert into mytable values('I''m quoted','I am not');
```

this will work. But i add

```
Insert into mytable values('I'mquotes','I am not');
```

it will create a bug cause it will take I as one value and then it will search for a coma separating I and m. But i guess you know that.

Anyway, my doublequoting function doesn't work. Can you help me spot what's wrong with it? Is my logic wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Use the built-in QuotedStr?

Comment: Are you serious there's already a builtin method? x)

Comment: Just use parameters ....

Comment: ARGH!!!! Use parameters.  http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: Btw, even if QuotedStr() didn't exist, the StringReplace() function would allow you to write your own equivalent as a single statement.

Comment: Please don't use `QuotedStr`.

Comment: I just used QuotedStr but it doesn't seem to do the work. It's even worse...

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  A matter of taste, imo, but the OP should at least be aware of it.  Might moderate the temptation to re-invent the wheel massively.

Comment: @MartynA Choosing between parameters and hand built queries is hardly a matter of taste.

Comment: @MartynA I used StringReplace thank you, it works better than QuotedStr.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: @David: I wasn't meaning to suggest that the OP shouldn't be aware of Sql Injection (but then I regard the side of the road I drive on as a matter of taste, constable).

Comment: I don't really try to hack something here x)

Comment: It looks as though you don't really understand SQL injection. Even without SQL injection, you are making your life needlessly complex by attempting to quote queries yourself. Why would you spend time working out how to do that when parameters solve your problem instantly? Obviously it's entirely up to you what you do. But you did ask for advice.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Oh ok you were talking about those parameters. I tought you are talking about function parameters and i was wondering what they speak about ^^ Yeah i didn't tought about parameters, probably a better idea than what i'm doing

Answer (score 4):

The only answer here, on any platform that supports it, is to use parameterized queries.  While it may seem annoying or frustrating at first, it's far better, and worth whatever frustration you think you're trying to avoid by not using them.  They're actually easier and faster once you get used to them.

Comment: Yup, i just don't know how much parameters there are and doing this was my first tought. Anyway i made it worked with double quotes